# Java error: "incompatible types" message

Tags: java, incompatibletypeerror

I am getting an error in Java during compilation:

```
UserID.java:36: error: incompatible types
            + generator.nextInt(10);
            ^
  required: String
  found:    int
```

Here is the Java code:

```
public class UserID {

  private String firstName; 
  private String userId;  
  private String password;

  public UserID(String first) {
     Random generator = new Random();

     userId = first.substring(0, 3) + 
        + generator.nextInt(1) + 
       (generator.nextInt(7) + 3) + generator.nextInt(10);     //this works

     password = generator.nextInt(10) + generator.nextInt(10);   //Error is here

  } 
}
```

What is the reason for this error and how do I fix it?  Why is it not automatically promoting the int to a String?

Comment: In order to place an integer into a String you have two choices: 1.  `Integer.toString(yourint)`.  and 2.  Add blankstring to your integer like this `String mystring = "" + 25`.  If you don't, the compiler will let you know that you've made a mistake.  Rightly so, you are putting something where it doesn't belong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On the `password` line, you're adding Integers(When you want to be concatenating them) and putting it into a string without an explicit cast.You'll have to use Integer.toString()

So like this

```
password = Integer.toString(generator.nextInt(10) + generator.nextInt(10)
        + generator.nextInt(10) + generator.nextInt(10)
        + generator.nextInt(10) + generator.nextInt(10));
```

The reason it works in `username` is because you have Strings being added to integers the put into a String, so it's implicitly casting it to a String when concatinating.

Comment: I Suspect the OP is trying to concatenate multiple ints as strings, rather than add them together then convert the sum to a single string. So he should be wrapping each `generator.nextInt(X)` in `Integer.toString` rather than the sum of them all.

Comment: Yes. I agree that his goal is concatination, but in it's current state it's adding them. The solution is either Integer.toString() to to add a `"" +` before the whole thing.

Answer (score 2):

Better way *is* to use `StringBuilder`,

```
StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
sb.append(first.substring(0, 3));
sb.append(last.substring(0, 3));
sb.append(generator.nextInt(1));
sb.append(generator.nextInt(7) + 3);
sb.append(generator.nextInt(10));

userId=sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy fix is to add "" first, e.g.:

```
password = "" + generator.nextInt(10) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the return type of `generator.nextInt()` it returns an `int` but you're trying to assign it to a `String` that's what it says: *incompatible type* you can't assign an int to a String.